# How to read file from hdfs in python script when using Hadoop Streaming?

Tags: hdfs

My python script for mapper is like this:

```
import sys,re,string
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
dir_path = "user/lexi/data/"
sys.path.append('.')
for filename in sys.stdin:
    file_path = dir_path + filename.strip()
    rfile = open(file_path,'r')
    #cat = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop","fs","-cat",file_path],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in rfile.readlines():
           do something
```

for the sys.stdin, it is a **filenames.txt** file which containing a list of filenames like this:

```
123.html
124.html
125.html
...
```

all these html files are under "user/lexi/data/" on hdfs.

Then I ran it in hadoop streaming:

```
hadoop jar /hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar\
 -input 'input/filenames.txt'\
 -output 'test-output'\
 -file Mapper.py -file Reducer.py\
 -mapper 'Mapper.py' -reducer 'Reducer.py'
```

But I got this Error:

```
14/02/14 20:47:54 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/02/14 20:47:54 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/02/14 20:47:54 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/02/14 20:47:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/var/lib/hadoop/mapred]
14/02/14 20:47:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201401161224_3630
14/02/14 20:47:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
14/02/14 20:47:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/libexec/../bin/hadoop job   -Dmapred.job.tracker=head:9000 -kill job_201401161224_3630
14/02/14 20:47:54 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://mri-head.mri.cs.gmu.edu:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201401161224_3630
14/02/14 20:47:55 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
14/02/14 20:48:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
14/02/14 20:48:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
14/02/14 20:48:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=head:9000 -kill job_201401161224_3630
14/02/14 20:48:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://mri-head.mri.cs.gmu.edu:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201401161224_3630
14/02/14 20:48:26 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201401161224_3630_m_000001
14/02/14 20:48:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Command Failed!
```

Someone can help me out of this???
Really NEED HELP!!!

Comment: How many filenames do you have. Seems to me that you should not read the filenames but the files itself.

Comment: Hi Smegma, I got 230 html files in a directory. I tried to put the  directory that contains these files as **-input** parameter in hadoop command but don't know how to deal with a directory in python script. I need my python script to read data from these html files.

Comment: Try adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the python files.

Comment: Thanks! I already put this in python file. My solution is passing the input directory to py file and then get filename by "filename = os.environ['map_input_file']". This works!